# First message not arriving over an MSMQ/MassTransit Service Bus

Tags: msmq, masstransit

I've got a MassTransit ServiceBus running over MSMQ. It appears that the first message sent over the Bus doesn't arrive, but subsequent messages do?

Is there some initialization that needs performing on the queue or bus before the message is sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on a few settings in how much time the system needs to setup before everything will correctly route. If only first message is failing to end up in the right location, then likely the subscription data isn't propagated everywhere yet. http://readthedocs.org/docs/masstransit/en/develop/overview/subscriptions.html

Using Multicast subscriptions, the easiest choice, will require a few seconds after a endpoint has come up and register a subscriber with all other endpoints. If you can control the order of services starting up, then this can often be avoided by started back to front in the flow.

If you are using the subscription service, then that can also take a couple seconds to get data everywhere. It has to go through the subscription service but the subscription is send to everyone on the bus. This is tied to a SQL db, and latency to the db can effect this timing.

Lastly, if you are using static routing, then that should work immediately, because the subscription is setup upon startup.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the first message can also be lost on consumer restart for the same reasons (when the publisher and the subscription service are running fine)?

Comment: It depends on if you call the unsubscribe action when shutting down the Consumer. Assuming you don't, then no change to the subscription status is announced and messages will be delivered as expected. If you call the unsubscribe action during service shutdown, then there will be time the subscription does not exist.

Comment: After seven and a half years, the problem still seems to exist, I just hit it today. Waiting awhile before sending the first message doesn't make any difference.